# Event onbeforeunload isn't fired in Chrome Incognito

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, beacon, sendbeacon

I've been trying to send a beacon on `beforeunload` and it seems to work on pretty much all modern browsers, except Chrome in incognito mode.

This is the code that works in all modern browsers, except Chrome in incognito mode:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    navigator.sendBeacon("url");
}
```

Not even this code doesn't seem to work:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
    console.log('before unload') 
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong or is it just Chrome's fault?

Comment: The snippet you posted works for me on Windows 10, Chrome 80.0.3987.87 incognito

Comment: You shouldn't rely on onbeforeunload. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: I don't need it to be 100% reliable, but I'm curious why it doesn't work in incognito. Also I don't want to send a message to the user, just a beacon to the server.

Comment: All blocking actions most probably will be forbidden in incognito mode, so unload event may be triggered, but your function will not complete before window / navigator instance gets destroyed... a wild guess ... you can try to add an static iframe and try to trigger unload from it putting som JS code inside "srcDoc" attribute

Comment: Incognito is not the right way to test. In incognito, you still have your addons activated, which might interefere with the test. You should try on guest mode instead.

Answer (score 0):

What's your setup (SO, Chrome version) ?

On Chrome 80.0.3987.116 / Ubuntu 64 and Chrome 79.0.3945.130 / Windows 10 the below snippet works falwlessy:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  console.log("BEFORE")
  navigator.sendBeacon("http://www.google.it");
  // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
  event.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
  event.returnValue = '';
});
```

Screen of the request (incognito mode) sent on beforeunload:

[image]
Furthermore, notice:

> To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts
>   created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been
>   interacted with. Moreover, some don't display them at all.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: I don't want to show a prompt, just to send a beacon without interrupting the user from leaving the site.

Comment: The above snippet shows both dialog and console.log

Comment: What's your output for _navigator.sendBeacon(url, data)_ ?

Comment: I don't want it to show any logs, just to send the beacon.

Comment: Look at my edit and my screen from an incognito session

Comment: I did, but I told you, I only need to send the beacon, not show just message to the user and interrupt him.

Comment: If you want to avoid dialog just return undefined or null like window.onbeforeunload = function() { ... return null }